# List of elements near a map: best way to explain not-zoomable element

Tags: lists, maps

In a web application I'm working on it, on left side of the map there is a list of elements, used as shortcut to zoom in every elements details.

In the following screenshot, you can see an example (I removed some information from the list):

[image]

**Some notes**
- selected element is in orange background
- currently user select an element that has no coordinates, so the map does not zoom to the element
- user is always free to zoom/pan the map using the mouse

**Question**
It is clear that elements with the "black pin" on the right side has coordinates and ones without doesn't zoom ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are mixing elements that may or may not have coordinates? Could you provide a little more context?

Comment: No. And not only that, the icons are hardly visible.

Comment: @Stefano: I prefer to keep this list consistent with the same list there is in another page, where are listed all elements

Devin: thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @Vokail so, if the user clicks on an element that has no associated location, what would happen? More details will be shown? Where? Is there a way you could bind the element to a generic "zone", if a precise location is not available?

Comment: I agree with @Devin; the icons are invisible to me in the scaled-down screenshot, and I can only barely see them when I open the full-size screenshot. I suggest coloring the icons light gray or white. As for whether the lack of icon makes the lack of zoom clear, no, the impression I get is just that the selected element always has its icon hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is clear that elements with the "black pin" on the right side has coordinates and ones without doesn't zoom ?

**No.**

Personally the first thing i thought was that the black pin shows me navigation to that point, there might be 100 other cases where people think different things from that icon in that context, since its not universally understood.

Most Icons don't work good on their own, so you should add text. There are only a few icons that are universally understood (for example a trash bin for delete or a envelope for e-mail).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I don't totally agree with your point, because many  software have a lot of icons ( think of Excel, as example)

Comment: • microsoft applications
• good usability

Pick only 1